# Thread-safe singleton class using std::shared_ptr in C++(11)

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

What I am trying to accomplish is to create an efficient thread-safe singleton base class (as stated in the title).

So this is my singleton class, which is used via inheritance (see below).

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SINGLETON_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define SINGLETON_HEADER_INCLUDED
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class singleton
{
public:
        static T *get_instance(void)
        {
                if(instance.get() == 0 || instance == (NULL && 0) || !instance) {
                        instance = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T());
                }
                return instance;
        }

        static delete_instance(void)
        {
                delete instance;
                instance = (NULL && 0);
                return;
        }

protected:
        singleton(void);
        virtual ~singleton(void);

private:
        singleton(const singleton&);
        singleton& operator = (const singleton&);

        static volatile std::shared_ptr<T> instance;
};

template <class T> template *singleton<T>::instance = 0;

#endif
```

Here is the class in use:

```
#include "singleton.hpp"

class opengl_renderer : public singleton<opengl_renderer>
{
        friend class singleton<opengl_renderer>;
        etc...
};
```

So basically, I am looking for some tips and reviews on my class -> I feel as if it isn't working the way I imagine it should. But it is functional at its current state.

Comment: By the way, this is a prime example of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). The code merely has the *semblance* of actual, meaningful code.

Comment: This is off-topic. codereview.SE is for working code. This doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 10):

Your code doesn’t compile, and if it would compile, it would crash.

You are trying to assign a `shared_ptr` to a raw pointer. You are also trying to `delete` a `shared_ptr` and this leads me to believe that you don’t understand [what a smart pointer actually does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

In fact, your code contains a multitude of errors. More on that below.

First, about the use of `shared_ptr`. In fact, a shared pointer denotes *shared* ownership, and this is patently not the case here: the singleton is the owner, nobody else.

A shared pointer is inappropriate here, what you want is a `unique_ptr`.

Then, don’t expose a pointer to the user, expose a *reference* via `get_instance` (i.e. habe `get_instance()` return `T&`. And I would rename `get_instance` to plain `instance` (which is more C++-y), and rename the private field to something else.

Finally, reconsider your usage of a singleton in the first place. The singleton is generally considered an anti-pattern and real, legitimate uses are so rare that it doesn’t pay to have a singleton base class.

## Detailed code critique

```
if(instance.get() == 0 || instance == (NULL && 0) || !instance) {
```

This is doing the same check three times. Why? Once is enough – the latter is the correct usage.

But this code isn‘t thread-safe anyway, in fact, it’s not making any effort to be thread-safe at all.

```
return instance;
```

As already said, you cannot cast a `shared_ptr` to a plain pointer.

```
static delete_instance(void)
```

That doesn’t compile, it’s missing a return value. Also, who is going to call this method? It should never be called probably, so just delete it.

```
delete instance;
```

As mentioned above, this doesn’t work, and is meaningless. The whole point of a smart pointer is that you don’t need manual deletion.

```
instance = (NULL && 0);
```

This code makes *no* sense. What is it supposed to do?

```
virtual ~singleton(void);
```

You have declared the destructor but you haven’t *defined* it. The implementation will be empty but you still need to define it.

```
static volatile std::shared_ptr<T> instance;
```

`volatile` probably isn’t meaningful here. In particular, its meaning is unrelated to cross-thread access (unfortunately). But even if it was related to cross-thread access, this wouldn’t make your code thread-safe, it would simply mean that threads would read the most up-to-date version of the variable.

```
friend class singleton<opengl_renderer>;
```

What do you need this line for?

Answer (score 5):

Everything Konrad said.

But I would not even use a member to hold the instance.
I would make it a static member of the instance() method:

```
static T& instance()
    {
#if !defined(__GNUC__) || (__GNUC__ <= 3)
            static lock lockingObject; // gets lock in constructor
                                       // releases lock in destructor
#endif
            static T instance; // notice the static
            return instance;
    }
```

On g++ it is already thread safe (they have an extension the makes it thread safe). On other compilers you need to add a lock around the method (but only the first time it is called).

It is instantiated on first use and automatically destroyed.

See: [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289)